# Set items to disabled or in active state based on active items list from api in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, filtering, use-state

From the api I get a list of buttons which are visible for filtering:

E.g.:

button2
button4
button5

Let's say in total we have 5 buttons. `button1` and `button3` should have a disabled or in-active state (grayed out in ui) and be visible in the list:

button1 (disabled)
button2
button (disabled)
button
button

**Update:**

I got everything working, see my [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-dew-ffqj0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering the buttons, you can check whether the button is in active Buttons list from the api and apply styles accordingly like so:

```
    <button className={activeButtonList.find(el=> el === renderedButton) ? 'active' : 'disabled')}>SomeButton</button>
```

array.find will return undefined if button is not found in the button list and will evaluate to 'disabled'.
Hope this helps

Comment: Your question is clearer now so I am updating my answer.